# cannot reolve symbol issues in v21/values on adding appcompat-v7:22.1.1

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I have an app where I am changing my old implementation of ActionBar to ToolBar. In order to add a ToolBar I need to use **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** as my base theme so that later on I can add ToolBar as a supported action bar in my code. However this style/theme is not available in v7_appCompat version 19.1.0. Now If I change my appcompat to the newer version i.e.v7:22.1.1, it throws the following list styles saying, cannot resolve symbol on almost all of them.

**File name = v21/values.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/lmp-mr1-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Button"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display4" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Large"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse"/>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/lmp-mr1-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    </style>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/lmp-mr1-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu"/>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/lmp-mr1-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Subtitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title">
    </style>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/lmp-mr1-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Small"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Title"/>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/lmp-mr1-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Large" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    </style>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Small" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    </style>
```

The list goes on. I dont really understand why this is happening. If I dont use v21 or v22 of v7, then I wont be able to use the style **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar**. But If I change it to a newer version in Android Studio I am getting the above mentioned issues. Can anyone please help on How to resolve this? Whats wrong with this picture? Thanks

Comment: the newest version is 22.2

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the compileSdkVersion in your build.gradle